# Virtualize a windows boot partition over smb

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I would like to know, if it is possible, to virtualize a windows boot partition from a Linux machine, over smb?

I have only access, via the Admin Share C$, from my linux box through samba. I dont have any remote Access like TeamViewer or RemoteDesktop etc.

*Edit*: the reason why I need to access this way is (1) because I'm far away from it, and (2) it's a 24x7 produccion machine and cannot power it off for more than 1hr at most.

Comment: To be clear: it is not understandable what You want. You ask about "Virtualize a windows boot partition over smb" and tell "I can mount that that partition (C$) from a linux machine using samba, but don't have access to remote desktop nor TeamViewer or similar." which is very unrelated. Or do You mean You would like some kind of network boot for Your windows machine to get full control over it?

Comment: @EOhm, I only have access to that partition over smb, and want to create a VMDK, QCow2 or other kind of virtual disks from that share.

Comment: If You cannot get a disk image but all the necessary data for the image via SMB, You can create a local ntfs partition (on a disk or an image file) and copy the data over. Don't ask me how it works in the end, I assume it's not a no-brainer to get the file owner and permissions how they have to be to be usable as boot partition - and don't know at all whether current NTFS drivers for linux can make a FS a way that Windows acceppt it as boot device.

Comment: please explain why you dont have physical access to the machine, as superuser does not Support to make bad users cooies of remote Maschines

Comment: @djdomi, I added an edit explaining it.

Comment: in case it is a productive machone it must have a physical operator. so at this point you have to ask him to gain access, if he has not the rights the local it dep can help out. in 1 hour you could do a online image via acronis

Comment: @djdomi, yes, it seems that's the only thing I can do right now.